# Adding stream_results=True (execution_options) to kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLQueryDataSet

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, kedro

Is it possible to add execution_options to kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLQueryDataSet?

For example, I would like to add stream_results=True to the connection string.

engine = create_engine(
"postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost/example"
)
conn = engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True)

Here is my catalog.yml

```
table_name:
  type: pandas.SQLQueryDataSet
  credentials: creds
  sql: select * from table
  load_args:
    chunksize: 1000
```

Any idea on how to add/edit execution_options using pandas.SQLQueryDataSet?
Specifically, stream_results=True.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to create a thin layer over the existing `SQLQueryDataSet`:

```py
class CustomSQLQueryDataSet(kedro.extras.datasets.SQLQueryDataSet):
  def _load(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self._load_args["con"] = create_engine(self._load_args["con"]).connect().execution_options(stream_results=True)
      return super()._load(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then use this class in your catalog.